# IPN delivery failed. HTTP error code 404: Not Found

Tags: paypal-ipn, paypal-sandbox

I have implemented the IPN module for Paypal, and trying to test the IPN listener using my sandbox account.

However i get the above error.

I am using .NET MVC3 (C#)

Any help please

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

404 means the link you have pointed it to wasn't found, make sure you have it pointing to the right place and the right PHP script.

Make sure you also have no typos :)

Comment: Hi, Its not a php script .. its just a general link to an Action Method that is within MVC3